# Why does custom exception string print as array?

Tags: python, exception

In Python 2.7.x, I've created an Exception class:

```
class myException(RuntimeError):
  def __init__(self,arg):
    self.args = arg
```

When I use it:

```
try:
  raise myException("This is a test")
except myException as e:
  print e
```

It prints out like this:

> ('T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's'...)

I didn't print the whole thing but why isn't this printing out as a string? And how do I convert it?

Also, why is e.message blank?

Comment: Have you tried `def __init__(self,*arg):` (note the star)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`args` on an exception is special; it expects to be a sequence. Assigning a *string* to `self.args` is legal, it is a sequence, but it is converted to a tuple when you do.

Assign a tuple containing your argument instead:

```
class myException(RuntimeError):
    def __init__(self, arg):
         self.args = (arg,)
```

See the [`BaseException` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException):

> **args**
>   The tuple of arguments given to the exception constructor. Some built-in exceptions (like `IOError`) expect a certain number of arguments and assign a special meaning to the elements of this tuple, while others are usually called only with a single string giving an error message.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is:

```
class myException(RuntimeError):
  def __init__(self,arg):
    self.args = (arg,)
```